# Flash Export Size Limit

Tags: flash, size, export

I'm an avid user of Flash and use it promanently for my webcomic, however, there's a problem I've had for years which I haven't been able to figure out. Flash has atrocious export capability. It can't export animations properly, so I figured out how to use After Effects for that, but what I haven't figured out is the supposed size limitation Flash seems to set for itself.

My comic workflow goes like this: Draw it in Flash, export it as a PNG, and add certain extra details and formatting in Photoshop. When I draw in flash, I make my comics as big as I need them to be, far beyond the stage area Flash gives me. Often, I can export my image properly even though it's beyond the stage area, by choosing "Minimum Image Area" on my export settings However, if I've noticed that if at any point the width or height of my project reaches beyond 4000 pixels, including any masked or hidden artifacts, my export will glitch on me incredibly. To be more specific, should my image go beyond 4000px in any direction, it will export a file that features an incomplete version of my art split into 3 separate versions in 3 colors as ONE picture. It can't just seem to export big image files properly. Not only that, but working in flash, it will limit where I can go to in the window if my comic's too big. The only way I can access what's covering away from me is to unlock all the layers, which temporarily allows me to access the area it cut off until I stray away from it and it cuts it from view again.

Why is Flash doing this? Is there a limit to how much data it can process? Is there a way I can mess with the settings to make it not have such limits on its capability? How can I make it export properly?

Comment: I'll take a wild guess and say maybe it is something related to bitmap size limit? http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/size-limits-swf-bitmap-files.html

Comment: Perhaps, but I'm exporting in PNG, not as a Bitmap. Would that still influence the problem?

Comment: PNGs are still a type of bitmap (a raster graphics image). It's not the file type/extension I was referring to. Though maybe, try exporting as other file types and at different dimensions to see if this is indeed the case (the article seems to hint that there is a max of 16769025 pixels, no matter what dimension). Or maybe try exporting as fxg (should be vector) then sizing that up to however big you want it in illustrator (photoshop oddly could not read it).